# Dynamics CRM 2011 RibbonXML - ValueRule for yes/no field

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, ribbonx

I'm trying to create a `<ValueRule>` in RibbonXML for a two options (yes/no) field, for use in a `<DisplayRule>` that should show a button if the condition is true. However, I can't get it working the way I want.

`<ValueRule Field="somefield" Value="(what do I put here to represent "yes"?)" />`

I've tried with `1`, `true`, `Yes` and other variations in casings, but no matter what I enter, the rule evaluates to false and the button is hidden. How can I get this to work?

Comment: the values to use are "1" and "0", did you try both conditions?

Comment: Tried with both of them, neither works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my error - the field was missing from the form, so the rule didn't find anything to match. Added the field to the form, and 0/1 work correctly as values.